# Are filters compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

Suppose that we are given a [filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28mathematics%29#Filter_on_a_set) $F$ of subsets of some set $X$. We may identify each element of $F$ with a function in $\{0,1\}^X$, which is compact under the product topology. Is $F$ a compact subset of $\{0,1\}^X$?

Comment: I think you mean to say that $F$ is identified with a *subset of* $\{0,1\}^X$, not a *function in* $\{0,1\}^X$. Am I correct?

Comment: By Tychonoff's theorem, this is as asking if a filter is closed. The answer is, not always. The trivial filter $\{X\}$ is certainly compact, but a non-principal (free) ultrafilter is generally "pathological" and without properties which are generally true for Borel sets (let alone closed sets).

Comment: @AsafKaragila 's comment answers the question. There are only continuum many closed sets in $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ but $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ non-principal ultrafilters therein.

Comment: @Tomek: That's an excellent point to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A filter is compact iff it is principal.  Indeed, if $F$ is principal (generated by some set $A$), then it is closed in $\{0,1\}^X$ since it is the set of functions $f:X\to\{0,1\}$ such that $f(a)=1$ for all $a\in A$, and for each individual $a$ this defines a basic closed set and the overall condition is just the intersection of all these basic closed sets.

Conversely, if $F$ is not principal, then the set $A=\bigcap_{B\in F} B$ is not an element of $F$ (otherwise $F$ would be principal, generated by $A$).  But given any finite subset $Y$ of $X$, there is an element of $F$ that agrees with $A$ on every element of $Y$.  Indeed, every element of $F$ contains every element of $A$, so agrees with $A$ on the elements of $Y\cap A$.  For each $y\in Y\setminus A$, there exists some $B_y\in F$ which does not contain $y$ (since $A=\bigcap_{B\in F} B$), and the intersection of $B_y$'s for each $y\in Y\setminus A$ is then an element of $F$ that agrees with $A$ on all of $Y$.

This says exactly that $F$ intersects every open neighborhood of $A$, so $A$ is in the closure of $F$.  Thus $F$ is not closed in $\{0,1\}^X$, and hence not compact.

Comment: I think that this argument shows even more: namely that non-principal filters do not have compact bases.